# WordPress site impacted with redirect injection

Tags: wordpress, nginx, redirect, malware

I have a website that is running on an AWS server using the Bitnami Nginx and WordPress image.

https://www.athleticclubhk.com/

Recently it got all our ads on Google stopped due to malicious content. Oddly this time, its trickier then your standard malware of infected files. When visiting the site incognito, the first and only the first link click gets redirected using the following code:

`window.location.replace("https://cartoonmines.com/scount");window.location.href = "https://cartoonmines.com/scount";`

This is being injected on any link, however, upon investigating the loaded code on inspect its not injecting it into the page.

I've tried to hunt down the theme, plugins, core files and found nothing!

I replaced and reinstalled WordPress core files, deactivated all plugins and even swapped the theme - the problem is still there. I can't find any hidden .htaccess file in the entire root directory.

I even used GREP to try to look for anything fishy (any clues here that someone can help with?) nothing so far.

The site is still impacted with this so you can easily load the link ~ i do use malwarebytes to keep myself protected, incase you are opening this directly.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

The redirection code is implanted to `/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js`.

How to confirm:

- watch the cookies when clicking internal page, a new cookie is being set for tracking first clicks, named `ht_rr`
- save complete webpage locally and try to load it, and check in Chrome dev tools, you'll see that in Console tab it complains about this Javascript file attempting to set the aforementioned cookie

While a temporary resolution of deleting the file will fix things for some time...

There's no excuse for not setting up a proper server stack. Bitnami or other "great stacks" won't cut it security-wise. They exist for "fast", but no "quality" setup, and of course, it's never going to be secure.

The file got created somehow / had write privileges. This indicates a problem with the setup most of the time. Unless you're using some nulled plugins or plugins from bad sources.

Once again, since the website was essentially "pwned", deleting the Javascript file does not mean complete disinfection. To preserve things in a secure state, I would recommend setting things on a clean server environment with strict PHP-FPM permissions aka "lockdown" chmod, and look for write errors to look for infected PHP files.

Check out some guides on the matter of secure NGINX/PHP-FPM setup:

- [NGINX and PHP-FPM. What my permissions should be?](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-and-php-fpm-what-my-permissions-should-be)
- [Best practice secure NGINX configuration for WordPress](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/best-practice-secure-nginx-configuration-for-wordpress)
- [NGINX Security Headers, the right way](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-security-headers-the-right-way)

Comment: Thanks for this! The cookies finally make sense as to how the darn thing is working. 

Strangely the wp-emoji-release.min.js file was actually the same as a fresh download so i know for sure its the server that's compromised (which makes sense as the code looked all good to me).

This has now happened to two sites, both only had Jetpack as a common plugin between them. I'll migrate to a fresh ec2 (without bitnami) as you advised.

Anyway for me to find the culprit file doing this on the system?

Comment: A backdoor often hides with `error_reporting(0);`, you can grep `error_reporting` across all the files.

Comment: Thanks for this - i just dug through the 17 files that had 'error_reporting(' 

no luck :( - At this point i'm just curious which security hole caused it. Have even looked for any occurrence of the cookie name 'ht_rr' on the database and files and nothing. Probably the best hack i've ever seen till date!

Comment: Indeed, I checked, the `wp-emoji-release.min.js` is clean as it has empty diff with original. You can find the Wordfence plugin useful, as far as I remember it will allow you to check all the files against original versions. Then you can easily find affected files. Or much better, [use WP-Cli to verify file checksums against original](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/verify-checksums/): `wp core verify-checksums`

Comment: Mate I finally found it! I can't believe it but there was a plugin called Zend Font! I also now found a reddit post on this! 

https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/olnigz/ive_got_the_code_of_malware_that_infected_my_site/

Thank you so much for your help mate - ill take your advice on not using weak security AMIs!

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem and it was Zend Font Plugin, the same that some people mentioned before.

Installed Wordfence and this came out. Deleted the plugin and now the site is working perfectly.

Comment: Glad you spotted it! It was indeed my server's security compromised, after running tight permissions on a different EC2 instance, this never happened again.

Answer (score -2):

1. Disable plugins and check again.
2. Change the database username and password.
3. Ask the hosting manager to check the host.

Comment: 1) op said they did that already. 2) this does not sound like it has anything to do with any database. 3) what "hosting manager"? Op says they can grep their files so they have direct access.