# Wordpress hacked: Unwanted redirect to an external site if payment is successful or after logging in

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WP website designed by other person. there is an odd situation in this website which I'm confused about it:
when I log in to the site the website url changes to "cartoonmines.com/scount" while my website name is "topvegans.com"
this page also appears when people buy something and pay for it via payment gateway and the transaction is successful.

tests I have done with no result:

1. clearing all the caches
2. disabling all the plugins
3. going back to wordpress default theme
4. searching in all tables of database for "cartoonmines.com/scount"
5. downloading all the files and searching all the files for "cartoonmines.com/scount"

I simply expect to see my own website name after a true transaction or after logging in!!

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WordPress site impacted with redirect injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69349656/wordpress-site-impacted-with-redirect-injection)

Comment: Maybe try: https://www.google.com/search?q=Wordpress+hacked%3A+Unwanted+redirect+to+an+external+site+if+payment+is+successful+or+after+logging+in

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: @ADyson This doesn't seem to be related to the server, but more to a WordPress Redirect Hack.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec  not all the advice may be relevant in every case, but the site has been compromised, so I'd suggest the OP ought to be wary of vulnerability in general

Comment: It sounds like you should move your site to someone like WPEngine who can take care of applying security updates for you.   If you just let a WP site run without someone to manage security it will be hacked.